# How to extract role as reseller from this object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

role: "{"value":"Reseller","display":null,"type":null,"primary":null}";

Comment: The question is not very clear, can you please try to restructure it and add a bit more information on what exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: company: "RDR"
name: "Reseller Dev"
phonenumber: "90878878"
privilege: (6) ["Shop", "manageService", "WAN", "LAN", "Security", "Steering"]
reseller: null
role: "{"value":"Reseller","display":null,"type":null,"primary":null}"

Comment: from this data i want role as Reseller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the string is JSON you can do the following to get the value you want

```js
JSON.parse(`{"value":"Reseller","display":null,"type":null,"primary":null}`).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[data].role.value**:

```js
array = {
  role: {
    "value": "Reseller",
    "display": null,
    "type": null,
    "primary": null
  }
};
console.log(array.role.value)
```